# x64.nsh not working

Tags: 64-bit, nsis

I have encountered a piece of code in the web...
I have 64.nsh in my machine and as an example I have included in my code the following:

```
${If} ${RunningX64}  
MessageBox MB_OK "running on x64"  
${EndIf}
```

And it returns:

> ```
> !insertmacro:
> _If  !insertmacro: macro "_If" requires 4 parameter(s), passed 2!
> ```

Could you help?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Having the file on your system is not enough, you need to include the file in your code:

```
!include "x64.nsh"
${If} ${RunningX64}
MessageBox MB_OK "running on x64"
${EndIf}
```